# json import error in zeppelin 0.8

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I started to create google dataproc instance in version 1.3 due to some problems in version 1.2 . Zeppelin should be "version 0.8" because "dataproc version 1.3" installs spark 2.3 . I can export "zeppelin json files created in version 0.73" to 0.8. It does not throw error as expected. But if  I create a json in zeppelin 0.8 and then export this json to my local machine and then I try to import "json in local machine" to version 0.73 and version 0.8. Both threw same error. (invalid json). How can I correct this problem? same machine created json but cant read json it created. It is strange issue.

I copy the json created by zeppelin 0.8 below for your review. It includes one line spark code.

Thanks.

```
"{\"paragraphs\":[{\"text\":\"%spark \\n\\nval dd = 2\",\"user\":\"anonymous\",\"dateUpdated\":\"2018-07-19T12:58:54+0000\",\"config\":{\"colWidth\":12,\"fontSize\":9,\"enabled\":true,\"results\":{},\"editorSetting\":{\"language\":\"scala\",\"editOnDblClick\":false,\"completionKey\":\"TAB\",\"completionSupport\":true},\"editorMode\":\"ace/mode/scala\"},\"settings\":{\"params\":{},\"forms\":{}},\"apps\":[],\"jobName\":\"paragraph_1532005121582_199122006\",\"id\":\"20180719-125841_1980776305\",\"dateCreated\":\"2018-07-19T12:58:41+0000\",\"status\":\"READY\",\"progressUpdateIntervalMs\":500,\"focus\":true,\"$$hashKey\":\"object:523\"}],\"name\":\"ddd\",\"id\":\"2DNR1W1HM\",\"noteParams\":{},\"noteForms\":{},\"angularObjects\":{\"spark:shared_process\":[]},\"config\":{\"isZeppelinNotebookCronEnable\":false,\"looknfeel\":\"default\",\"personalizedMode\":\"false\"},\"info\":{}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and used https://www.freeformatter.com/json-escape.html to unescape the escape characters. Once you unescape the string that you have quoted in this question, make sure your remove the double quotes from the beginning and ending of it. You result will be a valid JSON, which you can import into Zeppelin.

PS: Make sure you remove any PHI or PII out of your initial JSON that you got from exporting the notebook. In other words, before you export the notebook, use the "clear output" function provided in the Zeppelin notebook.

PPS: You can also use "JSON Unesape" within Sublime Text.